# Using git diff to replicate changes in another directory

Tags: linux, git, diff

I have multiple websites structured (simplified) as follows under a single GIT repository:

```
/
/site-1
/site-1/index.js
/site-1/about.js
/site-1/package.json
/site-1/node_modules(not versioned)
/site-1/package-lock.json(not versioned)


/site-2
/site-2/index.js
/site-2/about.js
/site-2/package.json
/site-2/node_modules(not versioned)
/site-2/package-lock.json(not versioned)

/site-3
/site-3/index.js
/site-3/about.js
/site-3/package.json
/site-3/node_modules(not versioned)
/site-3/package-lock.json(not versioned)
```

I did some amendments in **/site-1/index.js**, **/site-1/package.json** and added a file **/site-1/changes.md**.
The changes were done in 2 separate git commit in a feature branch called **feature/carousel**.

I want to apply the same changes in **/site-2** and **/site-3**.

I've tried the following:

1. `git format-patch master -o patches` to retrieve the new diff in this feature branch with regards to **master** branch, but i was unable to apply the diff in **/site-2** and **/site-3**.
2. `diff -ruN site-1 site-2 > PatchFile1` to generate a consolidated diff, but it takes into account files that have been modified in **/site-2** as well and its not a generic diff that can be applied directly to **/site-3**

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git apply` with the `--directory` option to apply a patch to another main directory, as explained here:

https://blog.soltysiak.it/en/2017/08/how-to-use-git-patch-system-to-apply-changes-into-another-folder-structure/

First, create a patch file `changes.patch` based on the changes applied to directory `site-1`. Then you can do the following:

```
git apply -p1 --directory='site-2' changes.patch
git apply -p1 --directory='site-3' changes.patch
```

`-p1` removes the site folder from the patch headers, which is the main part that differs between the different directories.

`--directory='site-2'` will cause the `site-2` prefix to be added to each header in the patch